# hiding and showing parts of page with Jquery and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, w2ui

```js
function init_json_table(element) {
    var table_name = element;
    $.ajax({
      url:'get_structure',
      type:"POST",
      data: JSON.stringify({"table":table_name}),
      contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType:"json",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#' + element).w2grid(data);
      }
    })
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  //initilize all tables on page - fetch data from server
   $('.table').each(function() {
      init_json_table($(this).attr('id'));
   });
   // hiding and showing sections on click
    $('header nav a').click(function() {
        var $linkClicked = $(this).attr('href');
        document.location.hash = $linkClicked;
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $("header nav a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $('#main-content section').hide();
            $($linkClicked).fadeIn();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    hash = hash.replace(/^#/, '');
    switch (hash) {
        case 'block2' :
            $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
            break;
        case 'block3' :
            $("#" + hash + "-link").trigger("click");
            break;
    }
});
```

```css
#block2, #block3 {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#block1" id="block1-link">block1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#block2" id="block2-link">block2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#block3" id="block3-link">block3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div id="main-content">
  <section id="block1">
    <div class="table" id=block1_table1></div>     
    <div class="table" id=block1_table2></div>     
    <div class="table" id=block1_table3></div>     
  </section>
  <section id="block2">
    <div class="table" id=block2_table4></div>     
    <div class="table" id=block2_table5></div>     
    <div class="table" id=block2_table6></div>     
  </section>
  <section id="block3">
    <div class="table" id=block3_table7></div>     
    <div class="table" id=block3_table8></div>     
    <div class="table" id=block3_table9></div>     
  </section>
</div>
```

I tried implementing this idea of page switching with jQuery:
http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads7/how-to-supercharge-your-sites-speed-with-ajax-and-jquery/demo1/#page1

The problem is my content isn't just text, but JS-based tables populated with ajax post calls. I want the whole page to finish loading (about 40-50 ajax calls), all JS tables to initialize and then achieve seamless switching between sections. However, only the first page (that is not hidden) loads fine, the rest of the pages load up with empty div's instead of JS tables.

EDIT: I found a workaround:

```
    $('header nav a').click(function() {
        var $linkClicked = $(this).attr('href');
        document.location.hash = $linkClicked;
        if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $("header nav a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $('#main-content section').hide();
//workaround
            $('.table').each(function() {
                w2ui[$(this).attr('id')].refresh();
            });
            $($linkClicked).fadeIn();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return false;
```

every time the page button is clicked I refresh all the javascript tables in the page. Unfornately this happens every time and is very time consuming.

Comment: Since the problem is related to populating the tables on page load, it would be helpful to see the code for the `init_json_table()` function...

Comment: I added the init_json_table() function

Comment: try `alert($linkClicked)` inside `click` event and let me know are you getting any alert?

Comment: yes I'm getting an alert

Comment: ok, so still tab content `show` and `hide` is not working? Check your browser console are you getting any js error?

Comment: no errors. I can see in console that all ajax calls finished with success, so the table is pulling the info from the server. However, only the main page (block 1) loads up the javascript tables, when I switch to the other tabs it's empty divs.

Comment: add `console.log(data)` before `$('#' + element).w2grid(data);` and let me know how many times you are getting console of data with not empty content for each table

Comment: I get 9 JSON objects in console, 1 for each table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145132/discussion-between-mahesh-singh-chouhan-and-susdu).